# DXA Model Service is not registered

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-2.0, model-service

We have installed Content service, Discovery service, and DXA Model service.
Since auto registration for DXA Model service is failing, as per DXA Model Service documentation from GIT Hub added the role directly in CD storage config for discovery service and Content service as follows

```
<Role Name="ContentServiceCapability" Url="http://system name:9081/content.svc">
    <Property Name="dxa-model-service" Value="http://system name:9083"/>
</Role>
```

After that as Services are up and running we tried to run the sample DXA application locally, We got the below error

> DXA Model Service is not registered; no extension property called
>   'dxa-model-service' found on Content Service Capability.

When we have validated the DXA Model Service using Postman we got below error

```
{
    "timestamp": [
        "String",
        "2018-05-29T09:31:29.070+0000"
    ],
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientHttpError",
    "message": "Unable to get response from OData service: 404 Not Found\r\n",
    "path": "/"
}
```

We have Used SDL Documentation along with below blogs

https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/category/dxa/

https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/install-model-service-dxa-2-0-as-a-windows-service

Can you please suggest If we are missing any configurations?

Comment: Did you run the Discovery Service Registration Tool after changing the config? Why/how did auto registration fail?

Comment: Below is the log file when I executed Discovery Service Registration Tool                                           
2018-05-28 16:58:22,385 ERROR UpdateCommand - Not able to find builder for capability: ContentServiceCapabilities. Skipping...
The Other Services like Context Service, Deployer Service, and Token service got registered without any issues.

Comment: share the command what you used to run auto-register of DXA Model service?

Comment: I have used the below command executed from discovery service installation folder `discovery\config>java -jar discovery-registration.jar update`

Comment: Hi Prasanna, it will be a lot more useful if you **edit** your question and add the relevant information like logfiles and commands etc. in there rather than trying to crop it into a comment. That way more people get to see it directly which should improve the likelihood of a sufficient answer.

Comment: What was the error you got while installing the DXA Model service using `installService.ps1 --register`? and what is the command did you exactly used to install the DXA model service, If this works you no need to update the config on discovery not required for manual discovery register.

Comment: Ensure to Publish the following items for DXA 2.0
a. Navigate to Categories & Keywords and select the Category Sitemap [Navigation]  and publish
b.  Navigate to \100 Master\Building Blocks\Framework\Developer\Templates and Publish the Generate Data Presentation TBB, while publishing removes the Republish only option.

Comment: Since you seem to have solved this issue yourself, please Answer your own Question (instead of describing the solution in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DXA Model service error in Postman

The above error occurred as DXA Model service capability is not added to discovery service as ContentServiceCapability node got added by mistake under WebCapabilty node as shown below in cd storage config of discovery service.

`<Role Name="WebCapability"> 
<Role Name="ContentServiceCapability" Url="Computer name:9081/content.svc">; 
        <Property Name="dxa-model-service" Value="Computer name:9083"/>; 
</Role>`

Once removed the ContentServiceCapability node, and registered the DXA Model Service using Discovery Registration tool the service worked without any issue.

> DXA Model Service is not registered error

The above error occurred due to Invalid OAuth Credentials in DXA Application Web.config.

Thank you, Rick, Velumurgan, and Bart for help.